# MVC Dynamic Page Permissions Using Authorize Attribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, permissions

I'm working on setting up my user permissions for my company's site, and we have several different roles and permissions that will have to be created. I have found some awesome information on creating the actual roles and groups, as well as how to implement them from [here](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/10/27/Configuring-Db-Connection-and-Code-First-Migration-for-Identity-Accounts-in-ASPNET-MVC-5-and-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx). However, this still requires the roles to be hard-coded into the authorize tag, is there a way to dynamically populate the authorize tag, so that I can have a page on the site that I can quickly assign different permissions to different pages, without having to just back into the code and modify the permission set for every single page I create?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Implement the following custom authorise attribute.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute (params string[] roleKeys) 
        {
            var roles = new List<string>();
            var allRoles = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CustomRoles");
            foreach(var roleKey in roleKeys) {
                roles.AddRange(allRoles[roleKey].Split(new []{','}));
            }

            Roles = string.Join(",", roles);
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/AcessDenied");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then add the following to the web.config

```
<section name="CustomRoles" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler,System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

and then, as an example

```
 <CustomRoles>
    <add key="UsersPagePermission" value="HR,Accounts,Developers" /> 
  </CustomRoles>
```

The on your controller or action or in the global filters (whichever you prefer :)) add the attribute

e.g.

```
[CustomAuthorize("UsersPagePermission")]
public class UserController : Controller
```

This will allow you to modify the web.config rather than code to change permissions.

Comment: The custom Http Unauthorised redirect is optional :-)

Comment: whoot! Helped for me! Thanks!

Comment: @cheesesharp **where does the `customRoles` go, which sections?** can you some clarification please. I am getting errors in my web. config. Also can you show both usage examples please.

Comment: @aggie i am having the same isse did you figure this out, also the the value in custom roles only show controllers, *how are the actions-ROLE inside the controller handled?*

Comment: Thanks for providing this. Instead of storing the role permissions in web.config, is there a way to do this in a database table and then expose a view that allows the admin to assign the Roles to Views? This would make it easy to manage the permissions remotely through the website instead of modifying the web.config file.