# MVC 5: appSettings in decoration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a filter I use to filter only certain AD member groups from hitting parts of my MVC site/app. The way I'm using it is, a pipe'|' delimited string of 'AllowedOUs' (organizational units) in an app key like this:

```
 <add key="AllowedOUs" value="Implementation Development|Implementation Engineering" /><!-- <<-can be PIPE '|' delimited list-->
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
[AuthorizeAd(Groups = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedOUs"])] //<-- but this bombs
public class UserProfileController : Controller
{...
```

Telling me `an attribute argument needs a constant`... so, is there another way to make this happen?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23250408/3585500) might be what you're after?

Comment: Not exactly. I want this to work by passing in the groups to each call and/or class so different groups can hit different functionality. I guess I could modify what's in that link to have a separate filter for each group, but that's more work/maintenance to add each group than just adding a key and ref it in the call.

Comment: What about classic asp.net [User.isinrole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx)?